# monaca 実機デバッグ 外部画像がいきなり表示されなくなった

Tags: monaca

monacaの実機デバッグで外部から引っ張ってきている画像がいきなり表示されなくなりました。

・iphone6s、xperiaZ4の両方で表示されません。
・同じネットワークに接続しております。
・ブラウザのプレビューでは表示されています。

原因がお分かりになる方解決方法をご教授いただけますでしょうか。
宜しくお願いいたします。

追記
ご指摘ありがとうございます。
ソースコードは下記なります。

```
<ons-template id="start.html">

   <div class="contents">

      <div class="box top"ng-click="myNavigator.pushPage('open_page.html', { animation:'lift' })">
         <div class="inner clearfix">
            <p class="toptitle">タイトル</p>
         </div>
         <img class="top_back" src="http://xxxx.com/aaaa.jpg" height="100%">
      </div>

・
・
・
   </div>
</ons-template>
```

Comment: 実際に表示に使用しているコードなども一緒に添付してください。この状態では回答を付ける事が出来ません。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。コードを追記いたしました。